# Is it possible to skip confirmation on app restores?

Tags: backup, restore, titanium-backup

i'm using Titanium Backup to restore my data and apps,but clicking "install" and "done" is driving me crazy. Is there a setting for that?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

"0-click" batch restore (as [the Market page](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.keramidas.TitaniumBackupPro&hl=en) describes it) is one of the features of the Pro version. You cannot do it in the free version, but purchasing a key for the Pro version allows you to perform a batch restore unattended.